# Правильное написание слова "помошник"

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте. В 70-х годах прошлого века (советское время) нас учили (а педагоги были сильные и грамотные), что в слове "помощник" пишется *Ш*. Почему сейчас пишут *Щ*? И как правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Одно из двух. Или педагоги были не сильными, а никакими, или Вас память подвела.
Слово помощник ***всегда*** писалось через Щ.
И дело даже не в том, что я это время хорошо помню, сама тогда же училась. Все словари, начиная с середины прошлого века есть в сети.
А "помощника" через Ш в них нету.
Вот Ожегов (у меня бумажный 1964 г.). **Помощник** - и никак иначе.
http://www.ozhegov.org/words/25371.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, педагоги имели в виду расхождение в написании этого слова через "щ" и произношении в нём этого согласного как "ш". Ни то, ни другое не менялось.

Answer (score 1):

Совершенно точно правильным написанием было и есть "помоЩник", а произношением - "помошник".